# How to Get Data from Android Service?

Tags: android, intentservice

I have a class that extends Application

```
public class MyApp extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        startService(intent);
        Log.i("Try","App ID = " + intent.getStringExtra("MyID"));
    }
}
```

I also have a Service that generates an ID.

```
public class MyService extends Service
{
    public void onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
         intent.putExtra("MyID", getID);
    }

    public String getID()
    {
        //code to generate ID
        return ID;
    }
}
```

My problem is I need to pass the ID from MyService to MyApp but the Log states "App ID = null".

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

1. Bind to the service and get your ID by calling mService.getID() (see: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html to learn about bound services);
2. From your service send a local broadcast passing the generated ID in intent extras. Register a BroadcastReceiver wherever you would like to catch the broadcast (see example code: [how to use LocalBroadcastManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager)).

Comment: Can you give me an example based on the code above?

Comment: I need my service to run on the background indefinitely but developer.android states that bound service don't.

Comment: I think, that the second option is better in your case, because the ID generation might take some time and you won't be able to get the value right after you start the service.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options:

- Using the service object itself (as singleton).
- Using AIDL.
- Using Intents.
- BroadCast Receiver

Comment: Can you give me an intent example based on the code above?